# Jquery animate submenu on hover isn't smooth

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, hover

I am developing a navigation bar with submenus. On page load, the bars load, and submenus are hidden. When you hover over a link, the submenu animates in. I prepared all of my code in a jsfiddel here: http://jsfiddle.net/6cAaN/

As you can see, it is working fairly well; however not perfectly. It is a bit buggy. Any ideas how I can sharpen up the following jquery to make the hover effect a bit smoother and better functioning?

Here is the jquery:

```
$("#menu-nav ul:first").css({"opacity":"0"});

    $("#menu-nav li").hover(function(){
         $(this).find('ul:first').stop().show().animate({
            "top" : "42px",
            "opacity" : "1"
         }, 300); 

    },function(){ 
        $(this).find('ul:first').stop().animate({
            "top" : "0",
            "opacity" : "0"
        });

});
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Seems pretty nice for me in Opera 11.10 and IE9. In what browser are you having problems?

Comment: firefox 4! the problem is in between when you hover and switch the mouse from the parent to the child. It flickers a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do to tighten the existing code as-is: There is a space beneath the `<li>` and above the dropdown `<ul>`. Where you have it set to `"top" : "42px"`, it's creating a gap that doesn't have the hover event attached, so it makes the dropdown "shake" as it tries to hide/appear simultaneously.

Instead of setting the `top` property, just change it to `padding-top` in each instance. It makes it a lot smoother and more "hoverable".

http://jsfiddle.net/Madmartigan/6cAaN/8/

Answer (score 1):

1. I would apply the padding to `#menu-nav LI` instead of `#menu-nav` This will increase the hover response area.
2. I would add `z-index: -1` to the `.sub-menu` class so it doesn't appear on top of the menu bar.
3. I would change `.sub-menu li` to `.sub-menu a` and add `display: block` - this will make the whole sub menu button click-able instead of just the link.

As suggested by Yury, [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) is a nice option for controlling mouse sensitivity and user error.

Just a few ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `hoverintent` plugin instead of `hover`. http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html